# postgres disable nestloop at query level

Tags: postgresql

I want to disable nested and merge join loops for all joins the query as hash joins are more optimal for my query, one way is to use the set statements right before the query such as below

```
set enable_nestloop=off;
set enable_mergejoin=off;
<<query>>
```

Is there any way to push these via hints into the query? One of the tool I use doesn't support multiple statements, so it cannot have both sets and query run in it. Obviously I don't want to set it at db or even user level, these settings are needed for a specific query. Don't see any hint in pg_hint_plan to disable nest/merge for all joins in the query. Any advice?

Comment: The big question is Why? Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for the problematic query? In plain text as an update to your question. The ddl for the tables and indexes involved would be helpful as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best workaround I can think of is to wrap your query into an SQL function and to set that parameters there:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myquery(param1 integer, param2 text, ...)
   RETURNS TABLE (col1 bigint, col2 text, ...)
   LANGUAGE sql
   SET enable_nestloop = off
   SET enable_mergejoin = off
RETURN /* your query without the SELECT */;
```

This example uses the new, better syntax for SQL functions, but it will work just as well with the old syntax.